# What word describes someone who would never criticize his or her country, city, community or group that he or she belongs to?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, american-english, british-english, vocabulary

There are people who would never have any criticism of country/city/community or group to which they belong to.

For example: Most people living in a certain city have to use public transport which is extremely overcrowded for daily commute. But they would describe it as adventure. They don't like it when someone criticizes the state of public transport just because they belong to that city and won't hear any criticism of it.

Is there a single word that could describe such people?

The word I am looking for could not be "Patriotism". "Patriotism" is limited to country. It does not apply to city or group or a community. And being patriotic doesn't necessarily mean that one has to be so irrational as to praise everything about it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Patriotic

> having or expressing devotion to and vigorous support for one's country.

Source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/patriotic)

An individual would be a **patriot**.

Comment: The word I am looking for is not Patriotic. Because Patriotism is limited to country it does not apply to community or group. Also being patriotic doesn't necessarily mean that a person has to praise everything about it. One could be patriotic and still criticize certain aspect of country.